# Need to implement mobile push notifications for our cordova based mobile apps, based on shopify

Tags: android, ios, cordova, shopify, webhooks

We need to implement push notifications for our cordova based mobile apps for our ecommerce store, which is powered by shopify. We need to send push notifications to users whenever they make a purchase, a product has been shipped etc. What is the best way to go about implementing user specific push notifications for mobile apps for our shopify store? I believe we would need to use shopify's webhooks for this right?

Couldn't find any relevant info on this topic anywhere so I had to ask this here. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the plugin **OneSignal Cordova Push Notification Plugin**
check here https://onesignal.com/

- you can use API for send the notification when customer make a purchase so you need to make some code with php in your store ..